Program which archives "files" from stdin to stdout, without hitting the disk?
Can anyone suggest a program which:

Creates some form of archive from stdin, out to stdout, with filenames, and without hitting the disk (the data is sensitive)
The program output will eventually be saved, probably on Windows, into two separate named files

The two objects to be archived are a public and a private key, which don't actually exist on the Linux system as files, but which I can create and provide on stdin. The program should create an output stream containing both objects, together with their names (in practice, this stream is sent to a remote client, which is probably Windows, and the client saves it as a file; the client then has to extract the private and public key from that file).
The obvious answer is [info-]zip, which can compress/store from stdin to stdout. However, it creates a filename of - in the archive, which makes it difficult to extract. I haven't found a way to run zip a second time to add (-g) a second stream.
tar won't, I think, accept a file from stdin - the only thing you can get from stdin is a filename.
I can think of another couple of options:

Manually create my own tar file; the tar format looks fairly straightforward
Using symlinks and mkfifo to make the input streams look like files, and then using zip's -@ or tar's --files-from=- to get the filenames from stdin

This is a lot of work, though, and I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything obvious.

This is for me XY problem. Why do not set password on private key and forget about these equilibristics?

@RomeoNinov: because the end-user may not want to use a password. It's a hassle to supply a password every time you want to ssh or scp, for example. And leaving an encrypted private key on disk is not a great idea unless you're absolutely sure you're using a good algorithm, with enough rounds, and so on.

You might be able to feed tar with directly from another program with process substitution, but you still get names like dev/fd/63 in the archive. And unpacking might be an issue. Why not just use some plaintext format, with the data perhaps base64 encoded? E.g. printf "%s: %s\n" "filename" "$(base64 <<< "mydata")". You could decode that with just Bash or zsh, though of course that might not help on Windows (but perhaps Powershell might?) Or even more usefully, use something like JSON instead.

@QF0, do you have information about ssh agents?

tar doesn't do compression, it uses other tools for that, but standard tools like gzip or bzip2 etc all take stdin input and produce output on stdout. Are you sure you need something special here?

@terdon: no, not at all sure :)  I just couldn't figure out how to handle all of the stdin, stdout, and file names. My answer does seem to handle that.

@ilkkachu: yes, that was my initial thought as well, but it eventually turned out that I can get useful names into the zip file, as per the answer below.

It seems like you're trying to archive multiple files, but if you take input from stdin where will the file boundaries come from?

You can create tar files from /dev/fd/x files pointing to pipes with things like:
bsdtar -s:/dev/fd/3:private.key: \
       -s:/dev/fd/4:public.key: -cf - \
       /dev/fd/3 3<(echo private) \
       /dev/fd/4 4<(echo public) |
  gzip |
  ssh host-where-they-are-to-be-dumped 'gunzip | tar xvf -'

With yash and its process redirection feature, or:
bsdtar -s:/dev/fd/3:private.key: \
       -s:/dev/fd/4:public.key: -cf - \
       /dev/fd/3 3< <(echo private) \
       /dev/fd/4 4< <(echo public) |
  gzip |
  ssh host-where-they-are-to-be-dumped 'gunzip | tar xvf -'

With ksh, zsh or bash using redirection from process substitution (same syntax as yash's process redirection, but different feature)
echo private and echo public above standing in for the actual commands that generate the contents of those files.

I cracked and wrote a script to do this:
#!/bin/bash

data=$(cat)
priv=$(sed -n "/<----SPLIT HERE---->/q;p" <<< "$data")
publ=$(sed -e "1,/<----SPLIT HERE---->/d" <<< "$data")

mkfifo key.private key.public
cat <<< "$priv" > key.private&
cat <<< "$publ" > key.public&

zip -0 --fifo - key.private key.public
rm key.private key.public

I've run it under strace and it doesn't appear to do any unexpected disk writes. Run as follows:
./myscript.sh < ifile > test.zip

'ifile' is the 2 files you want to zip, concatenated together, with a spacer line between the two files. This spacer is a single line with the text <----SPLIT HERE----> (or whatever the line in the script above is). The script:

Reads stdin into var data
Uses sed to get everything above the spacer line into var priv, and everything below into var publ
Makes two named FIFOs
cat's the priv var into the private FIFO, and the publ var into the public FIFO. These are run in the background (&) - this is important, but with small files like this probably not essential
Runs zip, with no compression, writing to stdout, and reading the two FIFOs
Deletes the two FIFOs. Note that the FIFOs never contained any data - there are no 'contents' which are sensitive data

So the script reads the file data from stdin, and writes it to stdout, with nothing recorded anywhere on disk. The zip file unzips normally to produce key.private and key.public.

So you have the sensitive data written in ifile then?

@terdon: in practice, ifile is never actually 'written' - it's created on-the-fly in C++, which execs this script, and then pipes the data to the script's stdin. For the test above, though, ifile actually is a disk file which does contain the sensitive data, to make it easier to test.

Whether cat <<< text uses a temp file or a pipe depends on the version of bash and the size of the text. In any case, note that bash variables can't hold NUL bytes and $(...) strips trailing newline characters, so you can't use that for arbitrary data.

You can use streamzip to create an archive from stdin and output it to stdout. This program reads data from stdin, compresses it into a zip container and writes the streaming zip file to stdout by default. No temporary files are created.
If it is important to save the archive directly to disk, you can use the -zipfile option.
It is important to remember that it may not be safe to use programs with sensitive data.
There are other programs for creating archives from stdin. The choice depends on the requirements and conditions of use.
